# JavaScript mail subject/ message autofill

Tags: javascript

I am trying to autofill the subject and message fields in an Outlook email using mailto:. Please, see the JavaScript below. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance. (besides, I am a newbie)

```
function submitForm()
{
    changeName();
    printPDF();
    sendEmail();
}

function changeName()
{
    var title = document.getElementById('salesOrder').value
    +" ";
    title += 
    document.getElementById('Project-Name').value
    +" ";
    title +=
    document.getElementById('Client').value 
    +" ";
    document.title = title;
}

function printPDF()
{
    print();
}

function sendEmail()
{
    var receivers = document.getElementsByClassName("receiver");
    var emailString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < receivers.length; i++)
    {
        if (receivers[i].checked == true) {
         emailString += receivers[i].getAttribute("email")
        +";";
            
        }
    }
    window.location.href = "mailto:"+emailString;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Basically, I would like to autofill the subject with 'Sales order' Project-name' 'Client' and message field with pre-set text. Std email- outlook. Thanks